# Create a loop for stat module based on multiple values from a dict

Tags: ansible

One can loop like so:

```yaml
- stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - /tmp
    - /home
```

Now, imagine this dict:

```yaml
my_dict:
  one:
    path: /somewhere
    file_one: filename.txt
    file_two: whatever
    some_var: 'not relevant'
  two:
    path: /foo
    file_one: filename.txt
    file_two: oui.nice
    some_var: 'not relevant'
```

When I want to loop over a certain value in the dict:

```yaml
- stat:
    path: "{{ item.value.path }}"
  loop: "{{ crt_to_gen | dict2items }}"
```

How would create a loop, so that it would stat the `path`, `file_one` and `file_two` for each key in the dict? I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: What are you looking for as an output for `one`? `['/somewhere/filename.txt','/somewhere/whatever']`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use `+` to [concatenate lists](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#math), you could zip a list of paths to the attribute `file_one` and then concatenate it with the same for `file_two`, all those using the usual [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "Path to file is `{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}`"
  loop: >-
    {{
      _paths | zip(my_dict.values() | map(attribute='file_one')) | list +
      _paths | zip(my_dict.values() | map(attribute='file_two')) | list
    }}
  vars:
    _paths: "{{ my_dict.values() | map(attribute='path') }}"
    my_dict:
      one:
        path: /somewhere
        file_one: filename.txt
        file_two: whatever
        some_var: 'not relevant'
      two:
        path: /foo
        file_one: filename.txt
        file_two: oui.nice
        some_var: 'not relevant'
```

This yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/somewhere', 'filename.txt']) => 
  msg: Path to file is `/somewhere/filename.txt`
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/foo', 'filename.txt']) => 
  msg: Path to file is `/foo/filename.txt`
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/somewhere', 'whatever']) => 
  msg: Path to file is `/somewhere/whatever`
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/foo', 'oui.nice']) => 
  msg: Path to file is `/foo/oui.nice`
```

---

*<sup>Note: I used the [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=values()#dict.values) method of Python dictionaries, to change for the usual `dict2items`, but it could also be used if needed.</sup>*

Comment: I'm using Ansible 2.9, receiving: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'zip' and 'zip'`.

Comment: Beside that *you should consider upgrading, because [2.9 support ended last year](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine)*. I guess this is a case of a casting not happening, once again, let me look at this peculiar case.

Comment: So, yes, in 2.9, you have to cast back two zipped lists to list. See updated answer.